# Symfony Form/ Doctrine: saving foreign keys of not yet persisted entities

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I've got a Symfony to create new records of the entity `News`. One of its properties is `$newsArticle`, which has a One-To-Many relation to the entity `NewsArticle` and holds the translations of the news record. 
My form should create a new `News` record and a related `NewsArticle` record (standard language) at once.
Imho the relations are defined correctly with the help of the @ORM Annotations:

```
class News {
    // ...  

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsArticle", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $newsArticle;

    // ...

    /**
     * Add newsArticle
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addNewsArticle(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle)
    {
        $this->newsArticle[] = $newsArticle;

        return $this;
    }
}


class NewsArticle {
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="newsArticle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $news;
}
```

The problem: after sending the form the News and the NewsArticle records are created, but the field `news_id` doesn't have a value.

Regarding to this problem I found in the [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#cookbook-form-collections-new-prototype) (*Doctrine: Cascading Relations and saving the "Inverse" side*) an example with a solution for a Many-To-Many relation:

> The trick is to make sure that the single "Task" is set on each "Tag".
>   One easy way to do this is to add some extra logic to addTag(), which
>   is called by the form type since by_reference is set to false:
>
> ```
> // src/AppBundle/Entity/Task.php
>
> // ...
> public function addTag(Tag $tag)
> {
>     $tag->addTask($this);
>
>     $this->tags->add($tag);
> }
> ```
>
> Inside Tag, just make sure you have an addTask method:
>
> ```
> // src/AppBundle/Entity/Tag.php
>
> // ...
> public function addTask(Task $task)
> {
>     if (!$this->tasks->contains($task)) {
>         $this->tasks->add($task);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you have a one-to-many relationship, then the workaround is
>   similar, except that you can simply call setTask from inside addTag.

Therefore I extended my code like this:

```
public function addNewsArticle(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle)
{
    $newsArticle->setNews($this);
    $this->newsArticle[] = $newsArticle;

    return $this;
}
```

... unfortunately this results in an error message:

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist
>   them in the entity manager?

I don´t have an idea how to solve this. Can anyone give me a hint, please? Or even a better solution for creating related entities that aren´t persisted yet?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The NewsController (excerpt)

```
public function addAction(Request $request) {

    $article = new NewsArticle();
    $article->setLanguageId($lang);

    $news = new News();
    $news->setPublic(0);
    $news->setDeleted(0);
    $news->setIdent($hash);
    $news->setRank($rank);
    $news->addNewsArticle($article);

    $form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news, ['languageId' => $lang]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($news);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Your changes were saved!'
        );

    }

    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:News:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'news' => $news,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Would just like to add that you don't have to flush in order to get the ID if you are operating on it in the same request. The only thing you need (from my experience using Symfony and Mongo at least) is persist; at that point you can starting using it as reference. Until you have used persist, the ID won't be available

Answer (score 0):

Seems I´ve solved the problem and it´s not in the code I´ve posted in my question but in the FormType code.

Comment: Can you post the code? It would help other people solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better, if you will persist all entities:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist([$news, $article]);
$em->flush();
```

Good luck!